# Type Mismatch in Scala Code

Tags: scala, functional-programming, parentheses

Here is the function for balancing parenthesis in scala. I am getting

> ```
> Error:(36, 10) type mismatch;
>  found   : Unit
>  required: Int
>         a=a+1
> ```

```
var a = 0

      def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
        if(chars.isEmpty)
          return Nil
        {
          if (chars.head == ')')
            a=a-1
          else (chars.head == '(')
            a=a+1
        }
        if (a == -1)
          return false
        if ((a == 1 || a == 0) && chars.tail.isEmpty!= 0)
          balance(chars.tail)
        if (a == 0 && chars.tail.isEmpty)
          return true
      }
```

Can anyone tell me why this error is coming?

Answer (score 4):

The code is full of errors.

You return `Nil` whereas your function has return type `Boolean`.

You define `else` with condition without `if`.

You use ambiguous condition `chars.tail.isEmpty!= 0`.

Fix these and repost your code. There are more errors but at the moment it is hard to tell whether you want to call recursively and return on empty List or return on some condition. If you still have problems then, I will update my answer appropriately.